# Dense Matrix-vector multiplication in VexCL

Tags: c++, opencl, gpgpu, vexcl

VexCL seems to be a very attractive library for gpu programming.

Unfortunately, its a very young library and there are few information over there. 
I've been searching how to execute a matrix-vector multiplication, but the only matrix representation I've found is vex::SpMat, which holds a sparse matrix.

If matrix is dense, then the sparse representations are less efficient for computations, usually.

All my matrix are dense and I want to know how to execute this efficiently in VexCL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am the developer of [VexCL](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl) library.

I have to admit dense linear algebra operations are not on my priority list. I believe it is very hard to implement those in a way that would be performance-portable across various devices supported by VexCL (that is, by OpenCL/CUDA). This task is probably best left to the vendor BLAS implementations (but patches are welcome!).

You may also want to look at the opensource [ViennaCL](http://viennacl.sourceforge.net) library, which does provide dense matrix operations and supports OpenCL, CUDA, and OpenMP backends. Their [autotuning framework](https://www.usenix.org/conference/hotpar13/workshop-program/presentation/Tillet) allows them to get portable performance which is close to vendor-tuned libraries.

Having said that, you have a couple of options (aside from providing a custom kernel) for the dense matrix - vector product in VexCL. First, you may use direct implementation based on definition of matrix-vector product:

```
using namespace vex;
Context ctx(Filter::Env && Filter::Count(1));

// The n x m matrix stored row-wise.
vector<double> A(ctx, n * m);
// The LHS and RHS vectors.
vector<double> x(ctx, m);
vector<double> y(ctx, n);

// Make an n x m matrix from vector x by replicating it along the first
// dimension (reshape), multiply it elementwise by A, and reduce the result
// along the second dimension.
// In other words, y_i = sum_j (A_ij * x_j)
y = reduce<SUM>(
        extents[n][m],  // Shape of the expression to reduce,
        A * reshape(
                x,
                extents[n][m], // (We need an n x m matrix...
                extents[1]     // ... but we only have vector of size m).
            ),          // the expression,
        1               // and the dimension to reduce along.
        );
```

With C++14 this could be easily hidden away into a function call:

```
template <class M, class V>
auto prod(size_t n, size_t m, M &&A, V &&x) {
    using namespace vex;
    auto NxM = extents[n][m];
    return reduce<SUM>(NxM, A * reshape(x, NxM, extents[1]), 1);
}
```

Second, you may just use vendor specific library. For example, if you use CUDA backend with VexCL, you could get raw pointers to VexCL-allocated memory regions and call cuBLAS [gemv](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemv):

```
double one  = 1;
double zero = 0;
cublasDgemv(
        cublas_handle, CUBPLAS_OP_N, n, m,
        &zero,
        A(0).raw_ptr(), m,
        x(0).raw_ptr(), 1
        &one,
        y(0).raw_ptr(), 1
        );
```

The first approach should be less effective than a call to cuBLAS. Its advantage is that the result of `reduce()` call is a vector expression and you could in principle combine several of those into a single fused compute kernel. For example, you could compute `Ax + By`, or `sin(Ax) + cos(By)`, or `(A + B)(x - y)`, or any other vector expression in a single kernel call:

```
z = prod(n, m, A, x) + prod(n, m, B, y);
z = sin(prod(n, m, A, x)) + cos(prod(n, m, B, y));
z = prod(n, m, A + B, x - y);
```

This could be more effective than several chained cuBLAS calls. I have [examples](https://speakerdeck.com/ddemidov/vexcl-at-pecos-university-of-texas-2013?slide=82) where VexCL outperforms cuBLAS by a factor of 1.5 due to this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I wrote the kernel that does the multiplication between them but I'm very bad at creating a good interface for using it. I will compare the speed of proposed methods and the usability of them, then I will choose one. Once again, thank you very much!